# SQL Server - job history for sql job running less than 15 seconds

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to figure out the issue.

we have a couple of sql job agents that runs less than 15 seconds everyday to execute store procedures.

Whenever I tried to see the job history, there is no information about it and it shows "never executed"

I did a simple test and tried to let it run say more than 60 seconds. I see it appears on the job history.

Is there any settings that I need to set so that I could see the jobs in job history that runs less than 15 seconds.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the job history being purged automatically perhaps?  Look at the SQL Server Agent properties under the History page and see if those settings are removing the history.  What happens if you run the job in 15 seconds manually?  Is the history visible then?

Comment: HI @squillman. I did a small test....I ran the job manually for 15 seconds no job history. but I then ran for 1 mins, yes job history.
so there is some settings somewhere which might set as 
"show job history only if its duration is 1 min or more."
for SQL Server Agent properties under History page - no tick for "remove agent history"